# Venishmartem Halachic guidelines regarding large gathering of Jews

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Following the horrible tragedy at Miron, where 45 Jews lost their lives in a stampede,
I wondered that large-scale religious gatherings are very indeed very frequent, especially in Hassidic communities, where tens of thousands of followers gather to celebrate various religious or personal events. I've participated in a couple of such events and I was never told about any general or event-specific Halachic precautions.

[image]

*[avax.news](https://avax.news/wow/Reality_of_a_Grand_Hasidic_Wedding.html)*

I know that there are numerous government rules and standards (for example [Israeli standard ת"י 5688 - בטיחות באירועים המוניים](http://www.osh.org.il/site/news/news011707.html)) sanctioning such events and defining guidelines for emergency services, evacuation, etc.

Did Rabbinic authorities ever issue Psakim or Takkanot regarding observing Venishmartem in such potentially life-threatening events? Outside Israel, is there a Halachic requirement to align with the state law and to submit to the police and emergency services?

EDIT: Thanks to @Joel and @Mordechai for the fine Talmudic sources. I intended to ask about currently obligating trends in those communities or places.

Comment: "tens of thousands of followers" also attend Yankees games, _l'havdil_

Comment: יוֹם טוֹב הָרִאשׁוֹן שֶׁל חָג שֶׁחָל לִהְיוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת, מוֹלִיכִין אֶת לוּלְבֵיהֶן לְהַר הַבַּיִת... לְמָחָר מַשְׁכִּימִין וּבָאִין, וְהַחַזָּנִין זוֹרְקִין אוֹתָם לִפְנֵיהֶם. וְהֵן מְחַטְּפִין וּמַכִּין אִישׁ אֶת חֲבֵרוֹ. וּכְשֶׁרָאוּ בֵית דִּין שֶׁבָּאוּ לִידֵי סַכָּנָה, הִתְקִינוּ שֶׁיְּהֵא כָל אֶחָד וְאֶחָד נוֹטֵל בְּבֵיתוֹ:

Comment: *Lichorah* the *halacha* would follow the professional opinion of what constitutes danger. Just as the *halacha* follows a doctor's opinion concerning which patient must eat on Yom Kippur.

Comment: [Moed Katan 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.5a.10): יוֹצְאִין לְקַוֵּוץ אֶת הַדְּרָכִים וּלְתַקֵּן אֶת הָרְחוֹבוֹת וְאֶת הָאִסְטְרָטָאוֹת ... וּמִנַּיִן שֶׁאִם לֹא יָצְאוּ וְעָשׂוּ כׇּל אֵלּוּ שֶׁכׇּל דָּמִים שֶׁנִּשְׁפְּכוּ שָׁם מַעֲלֶה עֲלֵיהֶם הַכָּתוּב כְּאִילּוּ הֵם שְׁפָכוּם תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר וְהָיָה עָלֶיךָ דָּמִים

Comment: @msh210 It's unlikely that the Yankees' ownership would ever request or follow halachic pesak regarding regulation of their events.